# sudo gem install cocoapods getting error

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, macos-sierra

Unable to install 'cocoapods' in my mac. I am currently using macOS Sierra.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)##
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the new [System integrity protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) feature introduced in El Capitan. It restricts even administrators from writing to /usr/bin.

If you don't want to do that, you can install CocoaPods to your home folder:

```
export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running it like this:

```
export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution when you are getting error like "**Operation not permitted**". Apply the command line by line in terminal...

```
 $ mkdir -p $HOME/Software/ruby 
 $ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby 
 $ gem install cocoapods [...] 1 gem installed
 $ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin
 $ pod --version
 1.5.3
```

Finally its working...